# UICollectionViewCell subclass that uses its parent's xib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, lets call it `CellClassOne`, and I'm trying to create a subclass of that cell, called `CellClassTwo` so I can change a property and modify some constraints in its view in `awakeFromNib`.

However, when I register my cell in my collectionView it gets loaded form the xib, so it has the parent's class, `CellClassOne`. How can I create `CellClassTwo` that can be dequeued by my collectionView and have its class set to `CellClassTwo` (and any properties and ovverides with that)?

I'm trying to avoid setting my properties in `cellForRow` since I'm trying to reuse my cell in different parts of my app but need slightly different paddings for some views, and I don't want to create duplicate Xib files for this.

If I must go with the duplicate files, then it may be better to stick with configuring the views in `cellForRow`.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that you can achieve what you are looking for via xib, but a viable way that should work is creating the CellClassOne programmatically ( including all the subviews and related layout constraints) following the cell lifecycles, and then subclassing it with CellClassTwo accordingly. That way you should be able to register the cell like ‘ collectionView.register(CellClassTwo.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")‘.

Comment: I think you're right. However the nib is quite complex so I wouldn't want to translate the whole thing in code.

I'll wait some more to see if someone has figured out a way to do this, otherwise I'll accept your answer that it can't be done :)